# Плагины на jQuery

Tags: jquery, slider

Всем привет!

Пишу собственный слайдер (слайдшоу) фоток на jQuery с небольшим набором настроек. Само собой логично делать такое в виде плагина.

1. Посоветуйте грамотные руководства написания плагинов на jQuery (русские и англ.) (просто общие онлайн учебники не интересуют - это всё уже есть).
2. В общих чертах каков должен быть алгоритм работы данного плагина (свой код не выкладываю, т.к. всё в процессе и много недочётов)?
3. И на данный момент загводка, как написать правильно плагин, чтоб слайдер был multiple (на одной страничке несколько штук работали корректно)?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Любите проектировать велосипеды? ))

1. Не знаю, может в вашей коллекции уже есть [эта ссылочка](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_jQuery), но если нет, то уж точно не помешает.
2. Алгоритм зависит от поставленных задач. Возмите для примера пару простых, уже кем-то написанных плагинов и разберите их на запчасти. Тогда поймете принцип работы, увидите недостатки и достоинства, которые учтете при написании своего безупречного шедевра.
3. Используйте классы, как основной селектор.

Comment: Благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Можете еще взглянуть на эту [статью](https://rsharpe-blog.ru/razrabotka-jquery-plaginov-sovety-i-praktiki.html), в ней как раз указаны некоторые моменты по данной теме. Если кратко то как такового "best practices" на мой взгляд нет. Каждый разрабатывает как умеет, в силу своих навыков/знаний. Посмотрите на те плагины, что наиболее популярны сейчас, попробуйте найти там что то общее, я думаю вы поймете о чем я.

Вот еще есть [статья](https://rsharpe-blog.ru/sozdaem-plagin-dlya-jquery-kak-v-bootstrap-3.html), там рассказывается о создании плагинов, которые по стилизации будут похожи как в boostrap